# Is there a drawback for local log in compared to server log in?

Tags: appsec, authentication, mobile

For developing a mobile app, there is a choice of storing usernames and password data in the device itself, or in a server (user will be authenticated to a server). Other than possibly the user have to manage multiple passwords if he has multiple devices, is there a drawback for the former choice? Also, the app is supposed to connect to internet anyway, so "no internet connection" is not an issue.

Comment: If the server is compromised what consequence would that have?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clarify your question to get a more helpful response.

Here's the generic answer: storing authentication credentials on a device puts those credentials at risk of offline attack. If a device is responsible for saying it is authenticated, then the somebody may spoof it.

Credential caching is not without merit or precedent. Windows systems perform credential caching for network-disconnected logins.